# How to execute multiple queries in parallel and distributed?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark 2.4.1 version and java 8.

I have scenario like:

- Will be provided a list of classifiers from a property file to process.
- These classifiers determines the data what to pull and process.

Something like the below:

```
val classifiers = Seq("classifierOne","classifierTwo","classifierThree");

for( classifier : classifiers ){
  // read from CassandraDB table   
  val acutalData = spark.read(.....).where(<classifier conditition>)

  // the data varies depend on the classifier passed in 
  // this data has many fields along with fieldOne, fieldTwo and fieldThree
```

Depend on the classifier I need to filter the data. 
Currently I am doing it as below:

```
if(classifier.===("classifierOne")) {
  val classifierOneDs =  acutalData.filter(col("classifierOne").notEqual(lit("")).or(col("classifierOne").isNotNull()));
  writeToParquet(classifierOneDs);                           
} else if(classifier.===("classifierTwo")) {
  val classifierTwoDs =  acutalData.filter(col("classifierTwo").notEqual(lit("")).or(col("classifierTwo").isNotNull()));
  writeToParquet(classifierOneDs);
} else (classifier.===("classifierThree")) {
  val classifierThreeDs =  acutalData.filter(col("classifierThree").notEqual(lit("")).or(col("classifierThree").isNotNull()));
  writeToParquet(classifierOneDs);
}
```

Is there any way to avoid the `if`-`else` block here?
Any other way to do/achieve the same in spark distrubated way?

Comment: your code is bad, 1) you're repeating the write method in each if condition and 2) it'salways the same dataframe `writeToParquet(classifierOneDs);` - you should read about how to use Scala properly ... `val df = if() else ...` and afterwards to the write once. Also Scala pattern matching is more Scala style ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems more about how to structure your application than Spark itself. There are two parts really.

> Is there any way to avoid the if-else block here?

"Avoid"? In what sense? Spark can't magically "discover" your way of doing distributed processing. You should help Spark a bit.

For this case I'd propose a lookup table with all possible filter conditions and their names to look up by, e.g.

```
val classifiers = Map(
  "classifierOne" -> col("classifierOne").notEqual(lit("")).or(col("classifierOne").isNotNull()),
  "classifierTwo" -> ...,
  "classifierThree" -> ...)
```

In order to use it you simply iterate over all the classifiers (or look up as many as needed), e.g.

```
val queries = classifiers.map { case (name, cond) =>
  spark
    .read(.....)
    .where(cond)
    .filter(col(name).notEqual(lit("")).or(col(name).isNotNull()))
}
```

`queries` is a collection of DataFrames to be `writeToParquet` and it's up to you how to make the queries executed in parallel (Spark will take care of doing it in distributed way). Use Scala Futures or another parallel API.

I think the following could make it just fine:

```
queries.par.foreach(writeToParquet)
```

With `queries.par.foreach` you essentially execute all `writeToParquet` in parallel. Since `writeToParquet` executes a DataFrame action to writing in parquet format that follows all the rules of Spark for any other action. It will run a Spark job (perhaps even more than one) and the job is executed in distributed fashion using Spark machinery.

Think of `queries.par` as a way to execute the queries one by one without waiting for earlier queries to finish to start a new one. You are strongly recommended to configure [FAIR scheduling mode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html):

> Inside a given Spark application (SparkContext instance), multiple parallel jobs can run simultaneously if they were submitted from separate threads.
>
> Under fair sharing, Spark assigns tasks between jobs in a “round robin” fashion, so that all jobs get a roughly equal share of cluster resources.

Comment: `foreach` runs on the driver and submit Spark jobs as if you used a series of Spark jobs one by one. It's more a coding trick not a Spark feature. The best is always to use web UI and see yourself.

Answer (score 1):

So, you need to select, what column to check, based on classifier name, that will be passed as a list?

```
val classifiers = Seq("classifierOne","classifierTwo","classifierThree");

for(classifier : classifiers) {

    val acutalData = spark.read(.....).where(<classifier conditition>)
    val classifierDs =  acutalData.filter(col(classifier).notEqual(lit("")).or(col(classifier).isNotNull()));
    writeToParquet(classifierDs);

}
```

As you're iterating through list, you would be going through all the classifiers anyway.
If column name can be different from actual classifier name, you can make it `List[Classifier]`, where `Classifier` is something like
`case class Classifier(colName: String, classifierName: String)`

Comment: If you want outputs to be written separately, to different paths - then you should look into Scala Futures, so that you'll be able to run all the processing at once, and then wait for result. Take a look at https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html, you'll need something like val classificationFutures = classifiers.map {cl => Future { // same code as before } }
val combinedFuture = Future.sequence(classificationFutures)
Await.result(combinedFuture, Duration.Inf)
(dirty code, just as example)

Comment: Other option - if you'll be combining results later in one dataframe, try 
`classifiers.map {classifier => //all the code without parquet saving, returning DF}.reduce(_ union _)` - this will give you single Dataframe with results of each classifier run (though I'm not sure if that is what you really need)